# Pass data to report from page

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, report

Is there a way that we can Pass data to report from web page
To be more specific I have a report to which I want to  bind dataset from Code behind,
I am using **ssrs 2008 r2**
with C# 4.0 ASP.NET 
Basically these reports will be viewed on browser, but what I want is to have something like we can pass the data from the page to the report

So far I found that there is **no direct solution** but is there **any workaround** ?

Comment: Why dont you try the solution that a while ago I posted [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12744336/binding-data-to-ssrs-rdl-from-code-behind/13416102#13416102

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using **XML** and pass the data from the page to the report server 
The XML datasource will generate dataset in the report and you can use it in your report

For detailed answer please take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12744336/binding-data-to-ssrs-rdl-from-code-behind)