# Is there a way to use datasets from custom assemblies to populate SSRS datasets?

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services, rdlc, rdl

I am tasked with converting some RDLC files to RDL that define their datasource with compiled VB.NET. Translating the code to TSQL is complicated for some of them, and it would be prudent to use the assemblies that are already developed if that is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Probably best option would be to make a host for assemblies which exposes data as xml webservice, then in a report to use xml data source.

Comment: Can the report server act as the host for the assemblies?

Answer (score 0):

**Usually** there is no way to access the SSRS report  dataset from **Code Behind**, you have to write queries for your Reports. But there is a kinda **work-around** . But it may have some performance issues..

Performance issues (Pros):

1. When you write your queries for the report, they are handled by ReportServer
2. and when you write stored procedures, they are handled by your Database server, in case your reporting server and database server are different

Performance issues (Cons):

1. When you don't want to go the above way and in the case you are developing the web application, you can surely make use of [passing data to SSRS rdl from code behind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12744336/binding-data-to-ssrs-rdl-from-code-behind/13416102#13416102) through XML 
   and the Cons is that your data processing at the moment is not done by Database server but by the Server in which your application lies