# generating an ssrs report using xml

Tags: xml, reporting-services, report

I need to generate an ssrs report using xml, but the xml gets its data such as columns etc from a storedproc. then once the report has been created I need to get the data to display using the sp

1)enter param, 2) sp1 gets the columns and param headers so it can write xml to generate the report
3) report then calls sp2 to get its data using the param and displays into the report

Comment: well that's my idea but don't know how to implement it. still new on reports. I am trying to avoid creating the reports manually as there are way too many

Comment: Check my answer and the link provided there, you will have an idea how to go ahead..and if you need any help, tell me

Answer (score 0):

The rdl file is simply xml. Without having done it before, try to create a basic report from scratch and try and emulate the code it produces.

In saying this, as a said, I've not  done this using xml just the gui.

Good luck mate!

Comment: Thanks for your response, however I know how to do the xml, but how do I tell the report use the xml to generate the columns etc and then use sp1 to retrieve its data

Answer (score 0):

ok,

we send the data to the reports through **datasets** and **datasources** 
so, we have a special kind of  dataset that can handle  **`XML data`** 
like for example :
Query for a dataset in ssrs

```
DECLARE @docHandle int DECLARE @xmlDocument varchar(max); DECLARE @listXML nvarchar(max)
SET @listXML = @list
SET @xmlDocument = @listXML EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @docHandle OUTPUT, @xmlDocument
SELECT *
FROM OPENXML (@docHandle, N'/ENVELOPE/ADDRESS') WITH (NAME nvarchar(max) 'NAME',CONTACT nvarchar(max) 'CONTACT',  STREET nvarchar(max) 'STREET')
```

Here **list** is the **parameter** you will send your **XML** through, to the report and this Dataset will process it,

For a complete example, I have replied a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13416102/1042705), if you read it carefully, you will get the idea of solving your question !